# How to write in next line of file blob in Azure with function

Tags: c#, file, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Im learning about AZ functions and i have a test practice.
I have **two containers**: **sample-items** (trigger) is where i save the files for run the function; **sample-logs** is where i need generate a file "BlobStorageTestLogs.txt" and inside of it, i must write line to line the log information of every file loaded in sample-items.

In this moment, my problem is: Ever when i write the new log in file, the value is overwritten (only remains one log) but i need write a new line and **i need to keep the pre-existing lines**.

How i can fix it ?

My function code:

```
[FunctionName("BlobStorageTest")]
    public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("samples-items/{name}", Connection = "testsandpracticesgrb18e_STORAGE")]Stream myBlob, 
    [Blob("samples-logs/BlobStorageTestLogs.txt", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "testsandpracticesgrb18e_STORAGE")]Stream outputBlob,
    string name, ILogger log)
    {
        string contentLog = $"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes";
        log.LogInformation(contentLog);

        //Write on file
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputBlob))
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(contentLog);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you are appending logs to your log file(BlobStorageTestLogs.txt), you can try using an append blob. See this link for a C# example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced and below are my expected results:

Appending a file in Storage account is possible by using below code:

```
    string cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rith8888;AccountKey=IacmavSEbo/L/tYxpfhhbCfFmiWUmdk7R5yMxa8p=core.windows.net";
    string cn = "samples-logs";
    string bn = "BlobStorageTestLogs.txt";

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(cs);

    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(cn);

    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(bn);

    string data;
    using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(blobClient.OpenRead()))
    {
        data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(data);
    string contentLog="vvvv"
    string updatedData = data+ contentLog;
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputBlob))
    {
                writer.Write(updatedData);
                writer.Flush();
    }
```

But, when you are doing or triggering Azure function, the Etag Property of Blob Changes due to which you are facing this issue.

[image]

In the trigger Statement we are saying to trigger whenever new blob comes trigger and create a output file, so new file is creating because of that.

To use Blob trigger and then upload and get logs as appended use below code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

namespace FunctionApp48
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "conn")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            string contentLog = $"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length}";
            log.LogInformation(contentLog);
            string cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rith8888;AccountKey=IacmavSEbo/L/tYxl4w==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string cn = "samples-logs";
            string bn = "BlobStorageTestLogs.txt";

            //getting previous data

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(cs);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(cn);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(bn);
            string data;
            using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(blobClient.OpenRead()))
            {
                data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            string updatedData = data + contentLog;
            Console.WriteLine(updatedData);
            //uploading appended data
            CloudStorageAccount st = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cs);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient1 = st.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cont = blobClient1.GetContainerReference(cn);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = cont.GetBlockBlobReference(bn);
            blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(updatedData);

        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

**`When Uploaded First File/blob:`**

[image]

**`Again after uploading 2nd file:`**

[image]

[image]

**`Inside Blob:`**

[image]

Prerequisites for my code to work are:

- need to have  a output container created
- need to have empty file at first

Comment: Its correct, awesome answer and clear explanation :)